# Using stream if property values are equal in both ArrayLists then combine them together in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Trying to combine two data, one for movies, the other for genres, only if the ids are the same from both properties.

Both got id, name fields, please consider the id in Movie is PK and Genre uses it as FK
like below so.

```
  List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
        movies.add(new Movie(1, "Titanic"));
        movies.add(new Movie(2, "Batman"));
        movies.add(new Movie(3, "Silence of the Lambs"));
        movies.add(new Movie(4, "1917"));
        movies.add(new Movie(5, "Fight Club"));
        movies.add(new Movie(6, "Inception"));
        movies.add(new Movie(7, "The Godfather"));
        movies.add(new Movie(8, "Peral Harbor"));

        List<Genres> genres = new ArrayList<>();
        genres.add(new Genres(1, "Drama"));
        genres.add(new Genres(4, "Drama"));
        genres.add(new Genres(8, "Drama"));
        genres.add(new Genres(7, "Drama"));
        genres.add(new Genres(2, "Action"));
        genres.add(new Genres(5, "Action"));
        genres.add(new Genres(6, "SF"));
        genres.add(new Genres(3, "Thriller"));
        genres.add(new Genres(5, "Thriller"));
        genres.add(new Genres(5, "Crime"));
        genres.add(new Genres(16, "Comedy"));
        genres.add(new Genres(3, "Horror"));
        genres.add(new Genres(1, "Disaster"));
        genres.add(new Genres(7, "Noir"));
        genres.add(new Genres(1, "Romance"));
                       ...
```

I wanted to tie them together if ids are equals and put genres array.

The result should looke like below:

```
result: [
                {"id": 1, "name": "Titanic", "genres": ["Drama", "Disaster", "Romance"] },
                                                  ...
                {"id": 5, "name": "Fight Club", "genres": ["Action", "Thriller", "Crime"] },

        ]
```

Barely got an idea to use stream or maybe not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the rudimentary code (don't have access to my IDE right now), but here's how I would approach it.

First, extend your `Movie` class with a list of strings that will hold the genres.

```
class Movie {
        int id;
        String name;
        List<String> genres;
        
        Movie(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    
class Genres {
        int id;
        String name;
        
        Genres(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Second, group your list of genres by their IDs:

```
Map<Integer, List<Genres>> genresGroupedById = genres.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.id));
```

Finally, iterate through your list of movies and assign the appropriate genres like so:

```
movies.forEach(m -> m.genres = genresGroupedById.get(m.id).stream().map(g -> g.name).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

That should get you started to make the code a little bit cleaner. :)

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class Movie {

    private final int id;
    private final String title;

}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class Genre {

    private final int id;
    private final String title;

}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class MovieData {

    private final int id;
    private final String title;
    private final Set<String> genres;

}
```

Then the main `combine()` method will look like:

```java
public static List<MovieData> combine(List<Movie> movies, List<Genre> genres) {
    Map<Integer, List<Genre>> mapGenres = genres.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Genre::getId));

    return movies.stream()
            .map(movie -> new MovieData(
                    movie.getId(),
                    movie.getTitle(),
                    mapGenres.getOrDefault(movie.getId(), List.of()).stream()
                            .map(Genre::getTitle)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'll represent the end result with another class, record is perfect for this use case:

```
record MovieWithGenres(int id, String name, List<String> genres) {

  MovieWithGenres(Movie movie, List<Genre> genres) {
    this(movie.id(), movie.name(), genres.stream().map(Genre::name).toList());
  }
}
```

Notice the additional constructor, which transforms the list of genres into a list of strings.

Then you have to group the genres by their movie id:

```
Map<Integer, List<Genre>> movieIdToGenres = genres.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Genre::movieId));
```

Now transforming list of `Movie` to list of `MovieWithGenres` is easy:

```
List<MovieWithGenres> result = movies.stream()
        .map(movie -> new MovieWithGenres(movie, movieIdToGenres.get(movie.id())))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or:

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> genresById = genres.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Genres::getId, 
                Collectors.mapping(
                        Genres::getName, 
                        Collectors.toList())));
movies.forEach(m->m.genres = genresById.getOrDefault(
        m.getId(),Collections.emptyList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not certain of the resulting data structure but it appears to be a list of maps.  The problem with the maps is that each value is a different type.  For `id` it is `Integer`, for `name` it is `String` and for `genres` is is `List<String>`

So I would opt for a class or record that combines the information.

In lieu of classes I am using records.  In the `Combined` record I am overriding `toString` to adjust the formatting.

```
record Movie(int id, String name) {
}

record Genre(int id, String genre) {
}

record Combined(int id, String name, List<String> genres) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  """       
    id     = %d
    name   = %s
    genres = %s%n""".formatted(id, name, genres);
    }
}
```

**The Data**

I changed `Peral` to `Pearl` and used `genres` as a list of `Genre`

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
movies.add(new Movie(1, "Titanic"));
movies.add(new Movie(2, "Batman"));
movies.add(new Movie(3, "Silence of the Lambs"));
movies.add(new Movie(4, "1917"));
movies.add(new Movie(5, "Fight club"));
movies.add(new Movie(6, "Inception"));
movies.add(new Movie(7, "The Godfather"));
movies.add(new Movie(8, "Pearl Harbor"));

List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
genres.add(new Genre(1, "Drama"));
genres.add(new Genre(4, "Drama"));
genres.add(new Genre(8, "Drama"));
genres.add(new Genre(7, "Drama"));
genres.add(new Genre(2, "Action"));
genres.add(new Genre(5, "Action"));
genres.add(new Genre(6, "SF"));
genres.add(new Genre(3, "Thriller"));
genres.add(new Genre(5, "Thriller"));
genres.add(new Genre(5, "Crime"));
genres.add(new Genre(16, "Comedy"));
genres.add(new Genre(3, "Horror"));
genres.add(new Genre(1, "Disaster"));
genres.add(new Genre(7, "Noir"));
genres.add(new Genre(1, "Romance"));
```

- First, I would simply group the genres by Id.  This is done as follows using `Collectors.groupingBy`.  `Collectors.mapping` is used to extract the genre name prior to adding in a list.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> idToGenreList = genres.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Genre::id,
                 Collectors.mapping(Genre::genre, Collectors.toList())));
```

- Now create a list of the combined information and populate using a loop.
- In the event that a genre does not exist for the map id, an empty list is used by default.

```
List<Combined> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Movie m : movies) {
     result.add(new Combined(m.id(), m.name(),
             idToGenreList.getOrDefault(m.id(), List.of())));
};

result.forEach(System.out::println)
```

prints

```
id = 1
name = Titanic
genres = [Drama, Disaster, Romance]
id = 2
name = Batman
genres = [Action]
id = 3
name = Silence of the Lambs
genres = [Thriller, Horror]
id = 4
name = 1917
genres = [Drama]
id = 5
name = Fight club
genres = [Action, Thriller, Crime]
id = 6
name = Inception
genres = [SF]
id = 7
name = The Godfather
genres = [Drama, Noir]
id = 8
name = Pearl Harbor
genres = [Drama]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Java Streams:**

You can try it with the below approach:

***Logic Here:***

Here, I have grouped the genres list by Id and created a map with key as id and value as List of String of genres. And then stream the movie list and created a new Object of Movie while streaming on the list and set the value of genres list using the map created above based on movie id.

**Code:**

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> groupById =
            genres.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Genres::getId,
                Collectors.mapping(Genres::getType,Collectors.toList())));

List<Movie> finalMovieList =
            movies.stream().map(x -> new Movie(x.getId(),x.getName(),
                    groupById.getOrDefault(x.getId(),Collections.emptyList())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Output:**

```
[{id=1, name=Titanic, genres=[Drama, Disaster, Romance]}
, {id=2, name=Batman, genres=[Action]}
, {id=3, name=Silence of the Lambs, genres=[Thriller, Horror]}
, {id=4, name=1917, genres=[Drama]}
, {id=5, name=Fight club, genres=[Action, Thriller, Crime]}
, {id=6, name=Inception, genres=[SF]}
, {id=7, name=The Godfather, genres=[Drama, Noir]}
, {id=8, name=Peral Harbor, genres=[Drama]}
]
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> genreType;

    public Movie(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Movie(int id, String name, List<String> genreType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genreType = genreType;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stream and Lambda expressions to merge datasets. By mapping the movie stream (movies. stream()) to the result stream (Result), for each movie, we filter out the genre that matches the movie ID (genres. stream(). filter (genre ->genre. getId()==movie. getId()), then map the genre name to a string list (. map (Genes:: getName)), and finally collect the results in a list (. collect (Collectors. toList())).

Please note that this code assumes that each movie ID has a corresponding match in the genre dataset. If there are no matches, an empty list of genres will be returned.

```
    List<Result> result = movies.stream()
                    .map(movie -> new Result(movie.getId(), movie.getName(), genres.stream()
                            .filter(genre -> genre.getId() == movie.getId())
                            .map(Genres::getName)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

Entity Class

```
class Result {
            private int id;
            private String name;
            private List<String> genres;
    
            public Result(int id, String name, List<String> genres) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.genres = genres;
            }
    
            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
    
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
    
            public List<String> getGenres() {
                return genres;
            }
    
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "{" +
                        "\"id\": " + id +
                        ", \"name\": \"" + name + '\"' +
                        ", \"genres\": " + genres +
                        '}';
            }
    }
```